# After updating npm and installing docpad permissions error occurs

Tags: node.js, npm, docpad

After running the following

```
npm install -g npm; npm install -g docpad@6.53
```

I get these errors in the middle of the install

```
 scripts/doc-build.sh: line 22: .building_ronn: Permission denied
    make: *** [man/man3/npm-bin.3] Error 1
    make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    scripts/doc-build.sh: line 22: .building_ronn: Permission denied
    make: *** [man/man3/npm-bugs.3] Error 1
    scripts/doc-build.sh: line 22: .building_ronn: Permission denied
    make: *** [man/man3/npm-commands.3] Error 1
    scripts/doc-build.sh: line 22: .building_ronn: Permission denied
    make: *** [man/man3/npm-config.3] Error 1
    npm ERR! addLocalDirectory Could not pack "npm" to "/var/folders/dj/vbwbhr8502s7clkgv1wpfw540000gn/T/npm-85093-ZDFFdytp/1382822267052-0.4880194154102355/tmp.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried it with sudo? i.e.

`sudo npm install -g docpad@6.53`

also, do you get this error when you install docpad on it's own from the command line?